# Model does not build for Linear Regression

Tags: python

I am trying to build a linear regression model but for some reason my model will not build. The shape for X is (10,2) and the shape for Y is (10,1). After the trained split the shapes are (8,2), (2,2), (8,1) (2,1) respectively. But no matter what I try the model will not build.

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")


#clean data for ease of use
age_bed = data.iloc[0:10, 1:3]
age = data.iloc[0:10, 1:2]
bed = data.iloc[0:10, 2:3]
death = data.iloc[0:10, 3:4]

#define the x&y data
X = age_bed
Y = death

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.2)
X_train.shape, Y_train.shape, X_test.shape, Y_test.shape

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, Y)
```

Only outputs:

```
Out[4]: LinearRegression()
```

When it is suppose to return something similar to:

```
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None,
         normalize=False)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: there is nothing wrong, try to predict something

Comment: Note: you probably want to train your model with model.fit(X_train, y_train). Otherwise, there's no point to using the train_test_split.